# Using createMany in Laravel returns null error when array used is populated

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

I have a `$new` collection which consists of an array, which I `collect` to allow me to run various filters using the Collection functions.

Using `Log:info($new)` my final collection prints out the following:

```
local.INFO: {"1":{"name":"11","position":1},"2":{"name":"22","position":2},"3":{"name":"33","position":3}}
```

Once this is completed I use the following following method to create those records in my `QueueLane` model:

```
$new_records = $business->queue_lanes()->createMany($new);
```

You can see I do this by inserting via a relationship from my `$business` variable which is just a `Business` model. The `queue_lanes()` is the name of my related relationship to the `Business` model.

When executing this line I get the following error:

> [2022-01-29 06:18:01] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null
> violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null
> constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (19, null, null, null,
> 2022-01-29 06:18:01, 2022-01-29 06:18:01, 1, 4, null). (SQL: insert
> into "queue_lanes" ("name", "position", "business_id", "updated_at",
> "created_at") values (?, 1, 4, 2022-01-29 06:18:01, 2022-01-29
> 06:18:01) returning "id") {"userId":4,"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 23502): SQLSTATE[23502]:
> Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates
> not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (19, null, null,
> null, 2022-01-29 06:18:01, 2022-01-29 06:18:01, 1, 4, null). (SQL:
> insert into "queue_lanes" ("name", "position", "business_id",
> "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, 1, 4, 2022-01-29 06:18:01,
> 2022-01-29 06:18:01) returning "id") at
> /Users/Username/Sites/test-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)

The `QueueLane` model has a `name` and `position` attribute that should be populated but it looks like it isnt; and I can't tell why looking at the `$new` input array. The only possible cause I can think of is possible the array keys are what are being read as the column names instead of the nested arrays.

I also have the `name` attribute in my `$fillable` variable in my `QueueLane` model.

Edit:
I have tried running `$new->each(function ($row, $key) use ($business)` and inserting each $row record but this still brings up the same issue.

Second Edit:
My Business.php model

```
class Business extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'business_type_id',
        'vanity_url',
        'allow_self_check_in',
        'enable_self_check_in',
        'enable_multi_queue',
        'multi_queue_active',
        'accept_new_entrants',
        'enable_shortest_option',
        'default_shortest',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'is_active'                 => 'boolean',
        'enable_sms_sender_id'      => 'boolean',
        'enable_self_check_in'      => 'boolean',
        'multi_queue_active'        => 'boolean',
        'allow_self_check_in'       => 'boolean',
        'accept_new_entrants'       => 'boolean',
        'enable_shortest_option'    => 'boolean',
        'default_shortest'          => 'boolean',
    ];
...
```

QueueLane.php

```
...
class QueueLane extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'min_head_count',
        'max_head_count',
        'position',
        'business_id'
    ];
...
    const DEFAULT_QUEUE = '#Default';

    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $value == 'Default Queue' ? QueueLane::DEFAULT_QUEUE : $this->name;
    }
```

I don't have a protected variable in my Business or QueueLane model.

Comment: Have you tried passing it as an array of arrays as shown in the docs by calling the `toArray()` on the collection?

Comment: Try using `$new->values()` instead of just `$new` to ensure the collection contains a non associative array, because it looks like your collection does not have numeric keys starting from `0` and may end up being treated as an associative array in the end

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, I didn't know there was a values() function in Laravel however I tried this and got the same result.

Comment: @harishdurga I have tried both `$new->values()` and `$new->toArray()`, both bring back the same result.

Comment: Try `$business->queue_lanes()->createMany([['name'=>'My Name','position'=>1],['name'=>'My Second Name','position'=>2]])`  I meant to try with some static data to understand if the issue is either with using collection or something else.

Comment: @harishdurga Using the following array `[{"name":"test value","position":1},{"name":"test value2","position":2}] ` still returns this error: `Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: This is the detail on the next line of the log `DETAIL:  Failing row contains (35, null, null, null, 2022-02-06 01:17:44, 2022-02-06 01:17:44, 1, 4, null). (SQL: insert into "queue_lanes" ("name", "position", "business_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, 1, 4, 2022-02-06 01:17:44, 2022-02-06 01:17:44) returning "id") {"userId":4,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 23502): SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"name\" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: the `createMany` method should accept an array of attributes.

Comment: I have tried to replicate the issue you are facing but for me, it is working fine. I have used Postgres 14.1, Laravel 8.82.0, and Php 8.1.2. You mentioned that you have declared the name in the fillable property. Verify whether it is protected. Better add the code of both those models to the question to better understand.

Comment: @harishdurga I have updated the post with relevant pieces to my Business model.

Comment: @harishdurga I have figured out the issue, and it is indeed due to other code in the model file. If you look at my QueueLane model, there is a mutator which is affecting the column, when I comment `setNameAttribute`, the file saves as expected. For helping can you create an answer that explains this and I'll select it. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the answer. Thank you @InvalidSyntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `QueueLane` model where you have the `setNameAttribute` mutator which is causing the problem setting the `name` attribute value to null. In a mutator `$this->name` will return null.